# How to bind table to a list attribute for a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binding

I am facing an issue to post and bind data represented in a table to a list of objects property in a model class.

Here is my model definition

```
public class Design
{
    public Featuredproducttype[] FeaturedProductTypes { get; set; } 
}
public class Featuredproducttype
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public string Visible { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

I have an html table to represent each item in the `FeaturedProductType[]` as a row like this :

```
<table class="table responsive shopex-table table-hover no-margin">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Featured sub product type
            </th>
            <th>Label</th>
            <th>What to display?</th>
            <th>Display count</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>
                &nbsp;
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>

        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.FeaturedProductTypes.Length; i++)
        {
             <tr>
                <td class="vcenter">
                    <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#modal-window').modal('show', { backdrop: 'static' });">@Model.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Label</a>
                </td>
                <td class="vcenter">

                    @Model.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Lable
                </td>
                <td class="vcenter">
                    @Model.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Display
                </td>
                <td class="vcenter">
                    @Model.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Count
                </td>
                <td class="vcenter">
                    @Model.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Action
                </td>
                <td class="vcenter text-right">
                    &nbsp&nbsp<a href="#" title="move down"><i class="entypo-down-open-big"></i></a>
                    &nbsp&nbsp<a href="#" title="move up"><i class="entypo-up-open-big"></i></a>
                    &nbsp&nbsp<a href="#" title="delete" onclick="jQuery('#modal-confirm-delete').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});"><i class="entypo-cancel"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my controller action

```
[Route("{id:int:min(1)}/addDesign")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddDesign(Design model)
{
    //this one is empty:  model.FeaturedProductTypes
}
```

How can I bind each new row added to the table as an item in my model `FeaturedProductTypes` property?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an array and not e.g. `List<FeaturedProductType>`? Adding new items would be much easier then...

Comment: You aren't generating any inputs for post back (you don't even have a form element in your view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have a form element, and I have another inputs that being posted, only this table values are not.

Comment: @ChrFin actually no, there is no specific reason. But how it will make difference than using the array.

Comment: As I meantioned already: Adding a new item to the list would simply be `list.Add(newItem)`, but with the array you need to "resize" it on your own and it seems like this can be the case here, as you are editing the list...

Comment: I repeat, you do not have any inputs representing your properties of `FeaturedProductTypes` (e.g. <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Label</td> or @Html.HiddenFor(..)

Comment: I treid using @html.label but it did not work for me. The problem is I am not able to use Html.TextBoxFor, it is generating an error for me.

Comment: Then post that error, as it should work as I just posted it in my answer...

Comment: No point using `@Html.LabelFor()` - that does not generate an input (which is what you need for postback). What error are you getting with `@Html.TextBoxFor`?

Comment: I do not need a textbox, i Just want to display the filed value and when I add a new record for the table using JS, I want to be able to have it as an item in the model list, ::                              I get this error using   @Html.EditorFor : The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from

Comment: If you don't want to edit it, but still want to post back the values, then use `<input type="hidden name="Fea... value=".." />` or  `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Feat...)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct id/name for the input elements for the model-binder to work:

If you generate the input elements on your own:

```
@Html.IdFor(m => m.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Action)
@Html.NameFor(m => m.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Action)
```

will get you the correct id and name for the input tag or use the following to generate the input tag:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Action)
```

Important is to use the indexed value of the model, e.g. the following will **NOT** work:

```
var item = Model.FeaturedProdictTypes[i];
@Html.NameFor(m => item.Action)
```

thus `foreach` can't be used directly.

**Update:**
Your table could be filled like the following:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.FeaturedProductTypes.Length; i++)
{
     <tr>
        <td class="vcenter">
            <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#modal-window').modal('show', { backdrop: 'static' });">@Model.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Label</a>
        </td>
        <td class="vcenter">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Lable)
        </td>
        <td class="vcenter">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Display)
        </td>
        <td class="vcenter">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Count)
        </td>
        <td class="vcenter">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FeaturedProductTypes[i].Action)
        </td>
        <td class="vcenter text-right">
            &nbsp&nbsp<a href="#" title="move down"><i class="entypo-down-open-big"></i></a>
            &nbsp&nbsp<a href="#" title="move up"><i class="entypo-up-open-big"></i></a>
            &nbsp&nbsp<a href="#" title="delete" onclick="jQuery('#modal-confirm-delete').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});"><i class="entypo-cancel"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your class;

```
public class Design
{
    public Featuredproducttype[] FeaturedProductTypes { get; set; } 
    public Featuredproducttype AddedItem { get; set; }
}
```

Then bind it with the model property AddedItem. Now you can add new item to your AddedItem array:

```
[Route("{id:int:min(1)}/addDesign")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddDesign(Design model)
{
    List<FeaturedProductTypes> productCollection = model.FeaturedProductTypes.ToList();
    productCollection.Add(model.AddedItem);
    model.FeaturedProductTypes = productCollection.ToArray();
    //do something more
}
```