# Add data to model on partialview load

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Kinda stuck on this one but I appreciate all I'm learning from everyone here on SO. I have a webgrid that loads a partialview when you select one of the rows. Displays company information and the partial displays more details. Works great.

Each company is assigned certain users, and users can be assigned to multiple roles in multiple companies. I'm trying to add the users to the partialview so they can be selected for editing, but every attempt I make to override the partialview in the controller results in no change. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Model

```
public class Clients
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int EINC { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public ClientUsers[] ClientUserList  { get; set; }
    public ClientUsers AddedItem { get; set; }
}

public class ClientUsers
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ReportingCompanyID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

}
```

View

```
@{
MyName.Models.Clients clients = new MyName.Models.Clients();
}
...
           @{
                var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 30, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
                grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);}
            <div id="gridContent">

                @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
                        headerStyle: "header",
                        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                        selectedRowStyle: "select",
                        columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column("Id", format: (i) => i.GetSelectLink(i.CompanyId), style: "compid"),
                        grid.Column("CompanyName", "CompanyName", style: "description")
                 ))

            @if (grid.HasSelection)
            {
                clients = (MyName.Models.Clients)grid.Rows[grid.SelectedIndex].Value;
                Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Client/_ClientAdminDetails.cshtml", clients);

            }
```

PartialView

```
@model MyName.Models.Clients
<h3>@Model.CompanyName<br /><em>@Model.CompanyId</em></h3>
```

Controller

```
// create a List and add query results to it, then add list object to model
// and return to partialview

        var q = from a in db.AllowedCompanies
                join p in db.CustomUserProfiles
                    on new { a.CustomUserProfileUserId, a.CustomUserProfileID }
                    equals new { CustomUserProfileUserId = p.UserId, CustomUserProfileID = p.ID }
                where
                  a.ReportingCompanyID == clients
                orderby
                  p.UserName
               // select new ClientUser()
               // {
               //     UserName = p.UserName,
               //     ReportingCompanyID = a.ReportingCompanyID,
               //     UserId = p.UserId
               // };

       // ObservableCollection<ClientUser> userlist = new ObservableCollection<ClientUser>(q.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at last answer, it could be helpfull
[Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802750/how-to-bind-table-to-a-list-attribute-for-a-model/24803372#24803372)

Comment: mashet - Thanx for the reply, I have edited my model to what I believe is required, but I have to admit being lost on the second "binding" part. I have created a PartialViewResult for _ClientAdminDetails() but it seems to have no effect, so I'm not sure where to even put anything. Your patience is appreciated.

Comment: I discovered that what I needed to do was change "Html.RenderPartial" to "Html.RenderAction", then I was able to modify to my heart's content. I am marking this as the correct answer because it did help a lot to get me thinking the best way to add the list array to the model object. Thanx again!